# Here Maps Javascript API - Malformed Request when trying to dynamically add multiple waypoints

Tags: javascript, here-api

So I have an MVC webapp that aims to search a vehicle by its plate, return a large string with latitude and longitude coordinates from my database showing where it's been through, and then draw a route on a map with every set of 'lat,long' as a waypoint.
I know that if I input every coordinate manually it works, but what I'm trying to do, since every plate is going to return a different set of coordinates, is assigning an array to routingParameters' via, using `H.service.Url.MultiValueQueryParameter()`.

I have an array named slice, which displays the following:

`["'-23.502750,-46.845710'", "'-23.502750,-46.845710'", "'-23.502655,-46.845567'", "'-23.502655,-46.845567'", "'-23.502655,-46.845567'", "'-23.506386,-46.838802'...]"`

I then assign it to via as such:

`'via': new H.service.Url.MultiValueQueryParameter(slice)`

and Here Maps API returns the following error:

```
{"title":"Malformed request","status":400,"code":"E605001","cause":"Error while parsing request: \n\n\tInvalid location specification at ''-23.502750,-46.845710''\n\tInvalid waypoint at ''-23.502750,-46.845710''\n\tUnexpected input at ''-23.502750,-46.845710''\n\tInvalid value for parameter 'via' at ''-23.502750,-46.845710''","action":"","correlationId":"e01765c2-9db1-465c-87bd-ab9b1e9cc444"}
```

Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

The following waypoint values should have only one pair of double or single quotes:

```
["'-23.502750,-46.845710'", "'-23.502750,-46.845710'", "'-23.502655,-46.845567'", "'-23.502655,-46.845567'", "'-23.502655,-46.845567'", "'-23.506386,-46.838802'...]"
```

for example

```
["-23.502750,-46.845710", "-23.502750,-46.845710", "-23.502655,-46.845567", "-23.502655,-46.845567", "-23.502655,-46.845567", "-23.506386,-46.838802"...]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!
I thought I needed those single quotes, as when you input each coordinate manually, you need to format it as such: 'via': new H.service.Url.MultiValueQueryParameter('lat,long','lat,long'...),

Comment: Hi, here is some information on what to do after you receive an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. I thought it might be useful